# Linq query - get first object of related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem with my query

```
var ninjas = from n in this.dbContext.Ninjas
                        join e in this.dbContext.Equipment on n.Id equals e.NinjaId
                        select ( new NinjaModel()
                        {
                            Id = n.Id,
                            Name = n.Name,
                            FirstEquipmentItemName = n.Equipment.FirstOrDefault()?.Name,
                            BornDate = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(n.BornDate).Value
                        });
```

I cant use FirstOrDefault in my query and I want to get first item name of ninja equipment there. Is it possible? I know I can use

```
 this.dbContext.Ninjas.AsEnumerable()
```

but then DbFunctions.TruncateTime wont work.

Comment: What do you want in BornDate property?

Comment: Why you cant use FirstOrDefault ?

Comment: Beat me by 9 secs, @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: BornDate is DateTimeOffset, I want truncate time from this.

Comment: You do realize you can wrap your entire query in `()` and do a `.FirstOrDefault()` on it, right?

Comment: @kriss and how is it related to equipment entities?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i can use FirstOrDefault() but I can't n.Equipment.FirstOrDefault()?.Name with ? operator

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy one ninja can have many equipment items.

Comment: Check for `null` and use `First`, if you can't use `FirstOrDefault` :P

Comment: @kriss but your previous comment was '*BornDate is DateTimeOffset, I want truncate time from this*'

Comment: @NicholasV. it's EF, you can't use First

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems is usage of null-conditional operator in query:

```
FirstEquipmentItemName = n.Equipment.FirstOrDefault()?.Name
```

That will give an error

> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating
>   operator.

What you need - just get name without null-conditional operator. In case if there is no related entites, name will have `null` value:

```
FirstEquipmentItemName = n.Equipment.FirstOrDefault().Name
```

What is happening behind the scene - EF generates SQL query which returns TOP (1) equipment name from related table. Something like:

```
   SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
    (SELECT TOP (1)
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Equipment] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Ninjas] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: Wouldn't that throw a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @EricWu nope. Don't think about EF expression as C# code. It's an expression tree which will never be executed. It will be translated into SQL query instead. And.. you cannot have NullReferenceException there

Comment: @kriss note that this trick will not work with non-nullable types. If sql query will not find any data in related table, it will return NULL as field value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.ElementAt(0)` which will return the first element from the query.
You can validate that there is actually an element at position 0 by using `if (ninjas.Count() > 0)`